# How to authorize backend to create SAS for Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure

I want to authorize backend (Web API in Azure Active Directory) to distribute SAS for uploading into Blob Storage.

It would be perfect if SAS can be issued only for one blob upload. I assume that client will send a request with a file name to upload, then backend will return SAS that could be used only to upload one blob with previously set file name.

I found the **Storage Blob Delegator** role, but as far as I know roles can only be set to user account (person).

How in this case the backend should be authorized?

1. Shared key
2. Fake account
3. Long SAS

Or is there another way to solve this problem? I have checked a lot of articles in docs but all of them solves slightly different problems.

Comment: You can't create a SAS for a non-existing thing, so... the closest you'll get is a SAS for some type of upload container (and you can grant limited access). That said: why grant permissions externally at all, vs managing uploads yourself? You're basically giving away your storage account name, folder/container strategy/etc. And you have to deal with expiring SAS, clock skew with SAS...

Comment: Empty blob would be created on client request, and after I wanna issue SAS for write only. According to azure web interface it's possible. But I haven't figured out how to do that through API yet.